# Why is this code showing error in my Brackets?

Tags: html, slider

I'm using Brackets to host my code and "> closing my slider-image appears as red. Then everything under it is red and green following the error. When posted below the code looks fine.

'''

```
<h1 class="slider-title">Trending Posts</h1>


<i class="fas fa-arrow-left prev"></i>

<i class="fas fa-arrow-right next"></i>


<div class="post-wrapper">
    

    <div class="post">

        <img src="https://i.imgflip.com/5jbbmk.jpg"" alt="" class="slider-image">                                                                          

        <div class="post-info">

        <a href="defense.html">Ideological Necrophilia</a>

        <br>

     <i class="far fa-calendar">  July 10, 2021</i>

        </div>
```

'''

Comment: Can you post CSS please

Answer (score 1):

There is additional quotation mark inside img tag.

```
<img src="https://i.imgflip.com/5jbbmk.jpg"" alt="" class="slider-image">
```

should be:

```
<img src="https://i.imgflip.com/5jbbmk.jpg" alt="" class="slider-image">
```

Comment: I dont think thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you didnt close the div tags for  `<div class="post-wrapper">` and `<div class="post">`

```
<div class="post-wrapper">


<div class="post">

    <img src="https://i.imgflip.com/5jbbmk.jpg"" alt="" class="slider-image">                                                                          

    <div class="post-info">

    <a href="defense.html">Ideological Necrophilia</a>

    <br>

 <i class="far fa-calendar">  July 10, 2021</i>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```